# Decreasing memory usage, C, CodeChef

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I'm doing this problem: http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL
I have the solution, but, the memory usage is coming out to be 1.6 MB, which, apparently, is too much. I don't understand how I can decrease this seeing that I have almost no persistent data. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int maxPower(long x) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<= 100; i++) {
                long myPower = pow(5,i);
                if(myPower > x) {
                        return (i-1);
                }
        }
}

int main (void) {
        int lines;

        scanf("%d", &lines);

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<lines; i++) {
                long temp;
                scanf("%ld", &temp);
                int five_counter = 0;
                int myPower = maxPower(temp);
                int power;
                for(power = 1; power<=myPower; power++) {
                        five_counter += floor(temp/((int)(pow(5,power))));
                }

                printf("%d\n", five_counter);
                five_counter = 0;
        }
}
```

As you can see, its written in C. Any ideas on how to decrease memory usage?

Comment: I might be totally wrong about this, but does it make a difference if you move your variable declarations outside the loops?

Comment: They get pushed onto the stack and then popped off at the beginning and end of every iteration. That might make it "execute slower", but wouldnt increase or decrease memory usage.

Comment: Rather than using `pow` (which is not guaranteed to give the correct answer), why don't you just multiply a running product by 5 at each iteration of the loop?

Comment: You have to be dividing by 5 anyway, so just keep dividing by 5.  The correct solution to this problem is really [quite short](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/355798).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i submitted and it was accepted

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
long n,q=0,t,c=1,result,z,m=5;
scanf("%ld",&t);
while(c<=t) 
{ 
scanf("%ld",&n);
z=0;
while(n!=0)
{
q=n / m;
z=z+q;
n=q;
} 
printf("%ld\n",z);
c++;
}
return 0;
}
```

**The main logic is that no of zeroes at the end of a factorial is the highest power of 5 that divides the number.**

Answer (score -1):

How much of that 1.6MB is shared memory? How much is local to your process? Simply by starting a process linked to the C standard library, you'll use a certain amount of memory, even if your entire program is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Where are you seeing the 1.6MB figure?

Comment: In the codechef my submissions. Its not letting me get a right answer because it gives me a Runtime Error (I'm 100% sure I'm not dividing by 0)

Comment: @Jeremiah: The algorithm is correct, more or less, it just is unnecessarily complex and inefficient.